# Rails/Active Record/Postgresql seem to be mis-naming my join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

In summary, the issue I'm seeing is that Rails is mis-naming my join table. It should be users_media, but Rails is naming is media_users. Below are the relevant details.

I have two tables that share a many-to-many relationship: **users** and **media**, and they are joined by table **users_media**.

Here's the generator I'm using to create said join table:

```
rails g migration users_media user_id:integer medium_id:integer
```

And here's the migration I'm running:

```
class CreateUsersMedia < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    reversible do |dir|
      dir.up do
        create_table :users_media do |t|
          t.integer :user_id
          t.integer :medium_id
          t.belongs_to :users
          t.belongs_to :media
        end
      end

      dir.down do
        drop_table :users_media
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here are the modifications I've made to the user and medium models respectively:

**user.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :media
```

**medium.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

Here's the error I get when I attempt to run User.first.media in Rails console. The crucial line is in bold. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
User Load (5.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
**PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "media_users" does not exist**
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"media_users"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"media_users"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum

**ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "media_users" does not exist**
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"media_users"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"media_users"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `has_and_belongs_to_many` association join table name is constructed in alphabetic order with both plural forms. Since 'm' predates 'u' in alphabet, join table should be named `media_users`.

Comment: Bingo! Many thanks, sir! I'll be accepting your response at the correct answer shortly.